# Adjusting edge and vertex label

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, graphs

I am using the following code (thanks to several answers on [TeX.Stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)) to draw a small bipartite graph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,arrows}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
  \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style =
    {shape=circle,fill=mygreen,minimum size = 6pt,inner sep=0pt}
  }
  \grEmptyPath[Math,x=0,y=0,prefix=d,RA=3,rotation=270]{2}
  \tikzset{VertexStyle/.style =
    {shape=circle,fill=myblue,minimum size = 6pt,inner sep=0pt}
  }  
  \grEmptyPath[Math,x=6,y=0,prefix=s,RA=3,rotation=270]{2}
  \tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->,font=\scriptsize}}
  \Edge[label = $0.005$](d0)(s0)
  \Edge[label = $0.002$](d0)(s1)
  \Edge[label = $0.100$](d1)(s1)    
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{graph}
\label{fig:graph}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image: small bipartite graph example]

I want to make a few more changes. These are as follows:

1. Move the vertex labels `d0` and `d1` to the left so that the edges don't cut across them.
2. Move the edge weights so that the numbers are places right above the edge and parallel to the slope of the edge.

*Note*: I was consulting [this manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/tkz/tkz-berge/doc/tkz-berge-screen.pdf), but didn't find helpful information regarding my issues. If you can provide a link to a more exhaustive document, it will be really helpful for me in future.

*Progress*: Added the line `\SetUpVertex[Lpos=-180]` before defining the vertex style for the left column, and then added `\SetUpVertex[Lpos=0]` before defining the vertex style for the right column (i.e., the `s0` and `s1` vertices). That solves the problem I had with vertex label positions.

Comment: It's a bit hard to help you when we don't know which packages you're using.  Please provide a full MWE.

Comment: Sorry about that. Added the packages.

Comment: You still haven't provided a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: My most sincere apology for not adding a `\documentclass` line at the top.  I am aware of the definition of an MWE, but isn't this nitpicking a bit too much?

Comment: Indeed it is. I just wasn't sure you knew what a MWE was since you didn't add the document class. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already solve the difficult part of problem: position of vertex label. The easy part is labels of edges. There you just add option `sloped`. So, the code of your MWE is:

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,arrows}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{80,80,160}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{80,160,80}

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}%<-- just to show figure only
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Classic]
\SetUpVertex[Lpos=-180]
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, fill=mygreen,
                               minimum size=6pt,inner sep=0pt}
  }
\grEmptyPath[Math,x=0,y=0,prefix=d,RA=3,rotation=270]{2}
%
\SetUpVertex[Lpos=0]
\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style = {shape=circle, fill=myblue,
                               minimum size=6pt, inner sep=0pt}
  }
\grEmptyPath[Math,x=6,y=0,prefix=s,RA=3,rotation=270]{2}
\tikzset{EdgeStyle/.style={->,font=\scriptsize,above,sloped,midway}}%<-- new options
  \Edge[label = $0.005$](d0)(s0)
  \Edge[label = $0.002$](d0)(s1)
  \Edge[label = $0.100$](d1)(s1)
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{graph}
\label{fig:graph}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In conversion from pdf to jpg are lost transparency of shapes with edge labels, so the picture is a little bit damaged.

Comment: Ah, perfect! But I also want the edge labels to be placed above the line.

Comment: no problem, just add option ``auto`` into ``EdgeStyle``. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: The labels are still poorly placed; they overlap the lines and are not centered between the two relevant dots.

Comment: In pdf picture the nodes of edge are just fine. This overlapping is caused by conversion from pdf to jpg. Labels are positioned as defined option ``auto``. This can be changed to select option ``above``. I will edit the code and image again ...

Comment: Instead of converting, you can take a screenshot of the pdf.

Comment: I still don't learn how to do this. I will try in near future. It is pity, that SE doesn't support pdf or eps, both basic output formats of LaTeX/pdfLaTeX. With this support the life of many contributor (at list me :) ) will become more happines.

Comment: @Zarko. If you want some suggestion, I use [GreenShot](http://getgreenshot.org/) for taking screenshots for my answers here. It can save the picture as .png. Two questions with more suggestions: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5954/most-efficient-workflow-for-displaying-imgur-hosted-output-of-tex-friends-so and http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3656/the-fastest-method-ive-seen-for-sharing-any-latex-image/3675#3675

Comment: @Ignasi, thank you for provided links. Recently I'm little bit more active on SE end I recognize that the way as I generate jpg pictures is not adequate (not in quality nor in time consuming). I see, that I need read meta SE too!

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{xfp}

\def\Label(#1)(#2)#3{%
  \psline{->}(#1)(#2)
  \pcline[linestyle = none, offset = 8pt](#1)(#2)
  \ncput*[nrot = :U]{$#3$}}
\def\pointL(#1)#2{%
  \psdot[dotstyle = o, fillcolor = green!80!blue](#1)
  \uput[180](#1){$#2$}}
\def\pointR(#1)#2{%
  \psdot[dotstyle = o, fillcolor = blue!60!red](#1)
  \uput[0](#1){$#2$}}

% parameters
\def\width{4}
\def\height{2}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.15)(\fpeval{\width+0.45},\fpeval{\height+0.4})
  \pnodes{P}(0,0)(\width,0)(0,\height)(\width,\height)
  \Label(P0)(P1){0.100}
  \Label(P2)(P1){0.200}
  \Label(P2)(P3){0.500}
  \pointL(P0){d_{1}}
  \pointL(P2){d_{0}}
  \pointR(P1){s_{1}}
  \pointR(P3){s_{0}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is change the values of the parameters and the drawing will be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: This is impressive! I didn't know about pstricks. I just did a side-by-side comparison of this and tkz-berge, and the edges definitely look neater in this approach.

Answer (score 2):

A try with [MetaPost](https://www.tug.org/metapost.html) and its [boxes](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpboxes.pdf) package, included in a LuaLaTeX program for convenience. (It can be made independent of LuaLaTeX if desired.)

**Edit** Note that it needs `luamplib` version 2.10.1 or higher. Previous versions had a bug concerning the `vardef` macros defined with a suffix (i.e. the `@#` of the `dot@#` macro here).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
  \mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{mplibcode}
    input boxes
    color mygreen, myblue;
    mygreen = 16/51(red+2green+blue); myblue = 16/51(red+green+2blue);
    ahangle := 30; ahlength := 7bp; % Arrowheads stretched: more visible at s1
    numeric r, h, v; h = 4cm; v = 2.5cm;
    circmargin := 3pt;
    vardef dot@#(expr c) =
      fill bpath@# withcolor c; drawboxed(@#); draw bpath@#;
    enddef;
    beginfig(1);
      forsuffixes s = d0, d1, s0, s1: circleit.s(""); endfor
      s0.c - d0.c = (h, 0); d0.c - d1.c = s0.c - s1.c = (0, v);  
      forsuffixes i = 0, 1:
        dot.d[i](mygreen); dot.s[i](myblue);
        drawarrow d[i].e -- s[i].w;
      endfor
      drawarrow d0.c -- s1.c cutbefore bpath.d0 cutafter bpath.s1;
      label.lft("$d_0$", d0.w); label.rt("$s_0$", s0.e);
      label.lft("$d_1$", d1.w); label.rt("$s_1$", s1.e); 
      label.top("$0.005$", .5[d0.c, s0.c]);
      label.top("$0.002$", .5[d0.c, s1.c]) 
        rotatedaround (.5[d0.c, s1.c], angle(s1.c-d0.c)); 
      label.top("$0.100$", .5[d1.c, s1.c]);
    endfig; 
  \end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

The dot `d0` is centered at the origin, the positions of the other nodes can be changed at will via the `h` and `v` parameters, as the dots' radius (value given to the `circmargin` variable defined in the `boxes` package).

[image]